# Null array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, null

I have script in JS:

```
$("#mailstextarea").on("change keyup paste click", function(){
    var text = this.value;
    var rez =  text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
    document.getElementById("emails").innerHTML = rez;

    for(var i = 0; i < rez.length; i++){
        addRow(rez[i]);
    }

})
```

When in #mailstextarea I type text with mails, I see this mails in div #emails, but I get error on rez.length „Cannot read property 'length' of null”. Why? Thanks!

Comment: ["An Array containing the matched results or `null` if there were no matches."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.match()` will return `null` if nothing is matched.

Just add a `if` check:

```
if (rez) {
    for(var i = 0; i < rez.length; i++){
        addRow(rez[i]);
    }
}
```

Or you could set `rez` to an empty array when nothing matched.

```
var rez =  text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi) || [];
```